# How to save created PDF file into dynamically file

Tags: c#, pdf

In my case, I need to let the user shoose the folder and the file name.
I know that I have to make some changes to "PdfWriterGetInstance".

Then how can I change my code to make it as I want:

```
 Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 42, 35);
        PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("Stock.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        doc.Open();
        Paragraph paragraphe = new Paragraph("Raport of Stock\n\n");
        paragraphe.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        doc.Add(paragraphe);
        DateTime now = new DateTime();
        Paragraph paragraphe3 = new Paragraph("                                                                                                                    " + now.ToString()+"\n\n\n");
        paragraphe.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        doc.Add(paragraphe3);
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dataGridView1.Columns.Count);
        //add the header
        for (int j=0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            table.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText));
        }
        //Flag the first row as a header
        table.HeaderRows = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i< dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1[k, i].Value != null)
                {
                    table.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1[k, i].Value.ToString()));
                }
            }
        }
        doc.Add(table);
        Paragraph paragraphe1 = new Paragraph("                                                                                                                     " + "Total items: " +quaq1.ToString());
        paragraphe.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        doc.Add(paragraphe1);
        Paragraph paragraphe2 = new Paragraph("                                                                                                                     " + "Total Price: " + tot1.ToString());
        paragraphe.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        doc.Add(paragraphe2);


        doc.Close();
```

Rq: I'm using iTextSharp Assembly.

Comment: What methods have you tried using for prompting the user for a filename?

Comment: `FileStream("Stock.pdf",...` dont hardcode this part. put it as parameter. however do make sure the path is valid..

Comment: Bagus Tesa Just I want to let the user pick the save director file .